# Why can't I chat, even though having 20 reputations?

Tags: support, bug, status-norepro, chat

I already have 20 reputations (which is the points to get chat) but I can't still chat. Why can't I?

Answer (score 9):

According to [your profile](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64499/matthew-roh?tab=reputation), you passed the 20 rep threshold 15 minutes ago. So, blame caching. The system sometimes takes a little bit of time to catch up and award privileges.

Comment: ([Details](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/95423/180276))

Comment: Aww. Thanks though.

Comment: I could wish someone to refresh, but thats impractical